# Nested virtualization not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, osx-mountain-lion

I installed virtualbox 4.2.10 on OS X 10.8.3 and I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on it as a guest. I have hardware virtualization enabled for the guest, as the screenshot shows

[image: screenshot]

But when I login to the VM and run `egrep '^flags.*(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` nothing appears. It seems virtualization is not enabled. What is wrong here?
Running `kvm-ok` in the host tells me

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions<br>
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```